# DiscriminatorColumn cannot be used in the query builder - php symfony

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have an entity Profile where is defined DiscriminatorColumn

```
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="user_type", type="string")
```

Entity Basic extends Profile. Entity Club extends Basic. I have Club Repository where i wanna write queries using DiscriminatorColumn user_type, I tried like this

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('profile');
    $qb
        ->Where($qb->expr()->isInstanceOf('profile', Profile::class))
        ->andWhere($qb->expr()->eq('profile.user_type', ':type'))
        ->setParameter('type', 'club');
```

And the error i recive:

```
message: "[Semantical Error] line 0, col 163 near 'user_type': Error: Class Bundle\\CoreBundle\\Entity\\Basic\\Club has no field or association named user_type
```

All solutions that I find on the internet say that solution is to use INSTANCE OF, I use it but didn't help, what I'm missing in the process?

Comment: what you want to select exactly ?

Comment: As I am sure you discovered by reading the many duplicate questions on this topic, you simply cannot use the discriminator column in your queries.  So start by removing the user_type stuff from your queries then follow the instance of example in the docs.  You really are making this much harder than it is.

Comment: @Cerad I start using INSTANCE OF, but that still doesn't help me.
yassinefikri profile which user type is club